# I need retrive WEB Account instead of SYSTEM user

Tags: spotfire

Into spotfire, I need identify the user who is logged in the web browser not the system user.

What variable I can use ?

This is the script I use for the SYSTEM user

from System import Environment

Document.Properties['userName'] = Environment.UserName

[Show web user in a variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ideN5.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%CURRENT_USER%` in information links. I only say this because usually when people want to know who is logged in, it's to limit the data that's being returned based off what the user can see. This is called **Personalized Information Links**.

For scripting, you can use this:

```
from System.Threading import Thread 
print Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```